# variable does not count characters from code correctly

Tags: c++

why does the spec variable add characters badly or in some strange way. When we see the code, there are if statements in the loops and if: if (check == special_characters [q]) then it should add spec = spec + 1; but for some reason, when I enter a digit, it also writes why to this variable
this is my code

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password;
    char check;
    int b = 0;
    int s = 0; 
    int d = 0; 
    int spec = 0;
    
    cout << b << s << d << spec << endl;
    
        char big_characters[26] = {'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M'};
            cout.write(big_characters, 26);
    cout << endl << endl;
        char small_characters[26] = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'};
            cout.write(small_characters, 26);
    cout << endl << endl;
        char digits[10] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'}; 
            cout.write(digits, 10);
    cout << endl << endl;   
        char special_characters[32] = {'`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=', '+', '[', ']', '{', '}', ';', ':', '|', ',', '<', '.', '>', '/', '?', char(34), char(39), char(92)};
            cout.write(special_characters, 32);
    cout << endl << endl;
    
    cout << "press any button \n";
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    
    cout << "enter your password: ";
        cin >> password;
    cout << "\t\t\tpassword: " << password << endl;
    cout << "password length: " << password.length() << endl << endl;
    
        for (int i = 0; i<password.length(); i++)
            {
                check = password[i];
                    cout << check << endl;
                    
                for (int j = 0; j<big_characters[j]; j++)
                    {
                        if (check == big_characters[j])
                            {
                                cout << "true \n";
                                b = b + 1;
                            }
                        else 
                            {
                                cout << "false \n";
                            }
                    }
                cout << endl << endl << endl;   
                
                for (int k = 0; k<small_characters[k]; k++)
                    {
                        if (check == small_characters[k])
                            {
                                cout << "true \n";
                                s = s + 1;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "false \n";                         
                            }
                    }
                cout << endl << endl << endl;
                
                for (int l = 0; l<digits[l]; l++)
                    {
                        if (check == digits[l])
                            {
                                cout << "true \n";
                                d = d + 1;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "false \n";                         
                            }
                    }
                cout << endl << endl << endl;
                
                for (int q = 0; q<special_characters[q]; q++)
                    {
                        if (check == special_characters[q])
                            {
                                cout << "true \n";
                                spec = spec + 1;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                cout << "false \n";                         
                            }
                    }
                cout << endl << endl << endl;               
            }
    
    cout << "big characters: " << b << endl;
    cout << "small characters: " << s << endl;
    cout << "digits: " << d << endl;
    cout << "special characters: " << spec << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

`

I expected everything to count as it should, but it doesn't work: / I would like to know why

Comment: Possibly with the exception of some of the "special" characters, you should be using [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) instead of making up your own (and most of your "special" characters seems to be covered by [`std::ispunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct)).

Comment: In order to check if a character is a capital, normally this is done like this: `(check>='A') && (check<='Z')`, but this only works if the letters are well sorted (which is usually the case in ASCII encoding and many others). Is there a reason to think that the letters of the alphabet are not well sorted?

Comment: Doesn't `for (int q = 0; q<special_characters[q]; q++)` only work if the characters are in ascending order?

Comment: Regarding the commend by @Dipstick, you have the same problem for the other loops as well. You seem to have skipped some crucial parts of your text-books, tutorial or class.

Comment: I sincerely hope your code isn't actually formatted like that. It's borderline unreadable

Answer (score 0):

In all your loops that look like this: `for (int j = 0; j<big_characters[j]; j++)`, the `j<big_characters[j];` part is nonsense.

You want to loop through all characters like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
```

Obviously it has to be the number of your specific array. So only 10 for the digits.

If you used a string or vector class you could even use their respective length getter to find out how many characters are in there, without repeating those magic numbers all over your code.

Comment: *for-range* also apply to C-array. but `std::/*unordered_*/set` would be even more appropriate, with a single `b += big_characters.count(password[i]);`.